# Get return value after SetTimeout

Tags: javascript, function, eval, return, settimeout

I've just asked about calling functions by name, now I want to process `return` statement after `SetTimeout`:

```
function ECall(funcName, arg)
{
    command += "(";
    for (var i=1; i<arguments.length; i++) 
    {
        command += "'" + arguments[i] + "'";
        if (i != arguments.length-1) command += ',';
    }
    command += ")";

    //var funcPtr = eval(funcName);
    //return funcPtr(arg); // This works, but I need SetTimeout

    setTimeout('window[\'' + funcName + '\']' + command, 1000);
}
```

`setTimeout` works great, but I have to save return value of called function. When I write: `setTimeout('alert(window[\'' + funcName + '\']' + command + ')', 1000);`
It alerts return value of function. How can I store it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use any of this string manipulation. Just pass a function reference to `window.setTimeout()`. To store the returned value of the function, simply assign it to a variable in the function you pass to `window.setTimeout()`

```
var savedValue;

function ECall(funcName)
{
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    var func = window[funcName];

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        savedValue = func.apply(this, args);
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to return a value from `ECall`, it won't work.

The `setTimeout` is asynchronous, which means that the `ECall` will return *before* the `setTimeout` code is invoked.

Or if you wanted the `alert()` to be part of the `setTimeout`, you could pass an anonymous function. Also, it would be better to not pass a string to the `setTimeout`.

I'd do this instead:

```
function ECall(funcName, arg)
{
       // Get an Array of the arguments, except for the first one.
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 );

       // Pass an anonymous function that calls the global "funcName" function
       //    inside the alert(). 
       // It uses .apply() to pass the arguments we sliced.
    setTimeout( function() {
        alert( window[ funcName ].apply( window, args ) );
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: You wrote that it's impossible to get return value after setTimeout, right? Are there any ways to do that?

Comment: @Ockonal: I used an alert in my answer, but @Tim Down shows the same concept [in his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211103/get-return-value-after-settimeout/5211190#5211190), but stores the result in a pre-defined variable (which is what you seemed to want). The value won't be available until the `setTimeout` runs of course.

Comment: Note from the future (2019): [`async function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)s address this problem nicely by allowing developers to write functions that "feel synchronous" meanwhile having their implementations use [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)s under the hood.